# Скачка всех файлов по ссылке

Tags: c#

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как скачать все файлы по нужному мне пути сайта.
Например www.mysite.ru/papka - papka это название папки с файлами

Comment: Ссылка вернет какой-то файл, например: html, json, png. Приведите пример папки с файлами. Хотя бы скриншотом :)

Comment: @gil9red http://rustfbits.tk/papka/

Comment: Внешне похоже на ftp, но это http(s), при клике на "папку" идет переход на ссылку с "папкой" и возвращается html с списком "файлов"/"папок", значит вам нужно скачивать страницу, анализировать ссылки в ней и если это файл, то скачивать его, если папка перейти по ссылки и снова анализировать. Для анализа страницы лучше воспользоваться html (xml) парсером, а в крайнем случае можно и регуляркой

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124492/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-command-to-get-directory-listing) вроде сделали что то подобное.